# react conditional render with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the screen first loads, I am getting some info from the server and setting state. If the user uses the select menu and chooses something else, it changes the state.

So, I basically am trying to say that if the state value is from the server, show that or if the state value is from the user selection, use that. I am also trying to use && to make sure first that there is even a value available at all.

```
const [country, setCountry] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   // get location via public IP lookup and set state of country c 
   //calling code based on IP eg: +44
   setCountry(countryInfo.data);
 }, []);

<Input
name="countryCode"
placeholder={
country && country.location.calling_code ? country.location.calling_code : country.callingCode }
width="20%"
editable={false}
/>

<CountryPicker
  name="country"
  theme={{ fontSize: 14, padding: 30 }}
  countryCode={
    country && country.country_code
      ? country.country_code
      : country && country.cca2
  }
  withCallingCode
  withFilter
  withCountryNameButton={true}
  withFlagButton={false}
  withFlag={false}
  withEmoji={false}
  onSelect={(country) => setCountry(country)}
/>
```

`country.location.calling_code` is coming from the server on initial load and `country.callingCode` is IF the user decides to change it via a dropdown.

The error I get is:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating country.location.calling_code)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the rest of the relevant code for this component.

Comment: There's a duplicate `: country.callingCode` at the end, is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry, yes. There was a duplicate which I removed now

Comment: You're checking `country` but not `country.location` before accessing to `calling_code`. Is there really a `location` property?

Comment: Also, you should include a [mcve], we can't really help you if we can't reproduce the problem on our side. How are you setting the state? How is it passed to this component? etc.

Comment: I am working on it.. There is a location property and I am getting calling code from it. if I console log the response from the server before setting state I use this and I see the calling code `countryInfo.data.location.calling_code`

Comment: @EmileBergeron, I have updated the question to show the sate that is set from the server and set once a user selects a country.

Comment: You should create 2 state value, the one from the selector, and the data from the server. Right now, you're mixing different types of data into the same state, which means you need checks everywhere and you're failing to make these checks properly. Fixing the checks (like the answers are suggesting) is only a patch to the design problem highlighted in my comment.

Comment: This can be a issue with the data that you are fetching too, you should include some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location may not exist either, so check to make sure it does.

`country && country.location && country.location.calling_code ? country.location.calling_code : country && country.callingCode || ""`

or

`country?.location?.calling_code ? country.location.calling_code : country?.callingCode || ""`

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and get error: `undefined is not an object(country.callingCode)`

Comment: That means country is undefined, so you need to do give a default value. I edited my answer.

Comment: So if country isn't defined yet adding `|| ""` will just make it an empty string until it gets a value.

Comment: I apprecaite your persistance. Still getting an error though, `undefined is not an object(country.callingCode)`

Comment: Sorry, mistake on my part, you need to check country again.

Comment: Hmm. Now I get `undefined is not an object(country.location.calling_code)`. This only happens when I try manually select a location from the picker.

Comment: show me what is the country is that object or what  console.log(country)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tow  shape first

```
country && country.location && country.location.calling_code ? country.location.calling_code : country.callingCode
```

or this shape it think  this shape for typescript

```
country?.location?.calling_code ? country.location.calling_code : country.callingCode
```

whitch meainng the  if the ? the item founb move to the property

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and get error: `undefined is not an object(country.callingCode)`